# How do i count task success/failure in ansible?

Tags: ansible

I am using ansible to set up a distributed application. i'm installing nodes, and then creating virtual interfaces, and cannot have more virtual interfaces than nodes. therefore, if i install on X nodes, and Y nodes fail, I need to check there are no more that (X-Y) virtual interfaces.

Is there a way to get, for a specific task, a numerical value of how many nodes succeeded/failed, so i can later use it to check the number of virtual interfaces?

Answer (score 0):

Use [ansible-runner](https://ansible-runner.readthedocs.io/en/latest/standalone.html). See [Runner Artifact Job Events](https://ansible-runner.readthedocs.io/en/latest/intro.html#runner-artifact-job-events-host-and-playbook-events) and "stats" in particular. For example ansible-runner and the playbook

```
shell> cat private3/project/test.yml
- hosts: test_01:test_02
  gather_facts: false
  tasks:
    - debug:
        var: inventory_hostname
    - fail:
        msg: Fail test_02
      when: inventory_hostname == 'test_02'
```

```
shell> ansible-runner -p test.yml -i ID01 run private3
...
ASK [fail] ********************************************************************
skipping: [test_01]

fatal: [test_02]: FAILED! => {"changed": false, "msg": "Fail test_02"}
...
```

created records in the directory `private3/artifacts/ID01/job_events/`. I'm not aware of any publicly available tool to analyze the events. I've created a playbook that displays failed tasks

```
shell> cat pb.yml
- hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: false

  vars:
    events_dir: private3/artifacts/ID01/job_events

  tasks:
    - find:
        paths: "{{ events_dir }}"
      register: result
    - include_vars:
        file: "{{ item }}"
        name: "{{ 'my_var_' ~ my_idx }}"
      loop: "{{ result.files|json_query('[].path') }}"
      loop_control:
        index_var: my_idx
        label: "{{ my_idx }}"
    - set_fact:
        my_events: "{{ my_events|default({})|
                       combine({my_key: lookup('vars', my_key)}) }}"
      loop: "{{ range(0, result.matched)|list }}"
      loop_control:
            index_var: my_idx
      vars:
        my_key: "{{ 'my_var_' ~ my_idx }}"
    - set_fact:
        my_list: "{{ my_events|json_query('*.{counter: counter,
                                              event: event,
                                              task: event_data.task_action,
                                              host: event_data.host}') }}"
    - debug:
        var: item
      loop: "{{ my_list|sort(attribute='counter') }}"
      loop_control:
        label: "{{ item.counter }}"
      when: item.event == 'runner_on_failed'
```

gives

```
shell> ansible-playbook pb.yml
...
skipping: [localhost] => (item=11) 
ok: [localhost] => (item=12) => {
    "ansible_loop_var": "item",
    "item": {
        "counter": 12,
        "event": "runner_on_failed",
        "host": "test_02",
        "task": "fail"
    }
}
skipping: [localhost] => (item=13)
...
```

Feel free to fit the playbook to your needs.